# Retrieve an object and save as new one with Hibernate/Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

In one of the services we perform some operations:

1. Update table A - call method with annotated query, method from repository, which extends JpaRepository.
2. Select from table B (repository.findOne(B_PK))
3. Modify retrieved object from point 2
4. Save modified object as a new entity (repository.save(B_Object))

Unfortunately, we are getting an error: "identifier of an instance of B_Object altered from X to Z". 
How we should do this in correct way??

Comment: Simplest approach may be to add a copy constructor.

Comment: But our objects are huge so it doesn't look to good...

Comment: So refactor your database first, which will probably improve performance anyway? I suspect that you're duplicating a lot of columns that could be normalized away.

Answer (score 1):

You should detach, object that you fetch in point 2 before changing and storing like new entity.

Answer (score -1):

Erase the unique identifier from the object (if it's auto-generated)

If doesnt have a autogen key you need to remove the constraints for the composite key.

Comment: The column has one column as a primary key and ID is generated by the sequence and triggers. Unfortunately, when I've added correct generation on the entity object it's still doesn't work. I needed to apply also the copy constructor, which chrylis suggested, but its ugly because our objects are too big for this...